# Swift: display a random array index every button click

Tags: swift

I have a swift class that reads lines from a text document and prints out the first line. After, every time a button is clicked a new line is read out.

What I want is to have a random line printed out the first time, and then a random line printed out after every button click.

Here's what I have so far:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class InfoController: UIViewController {

// MARK: Properties
@IBOutlet weak var difficultylevel: UILabel!
var i:Int = 0


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func readFile(){
    if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("easymath", ofType: "txt"){
        var data = String(contentsOfFile:path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)

        if let content = data {
            let myStrings = content.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.newlineCharacterSet())


            let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(myStrings.count)))
            difficultylevel.text = myStrings[randomIndex]
        }
    }
}



@IBAction func difficultybutton(sender: UIButton) {

    difficultylevel.text = // TODO insert random index of "myStrings" array here

}
}
```

However, I cannot access the myStrings array at the TODO portion inside the button click. Any help on how to set this up?

Comment: Make `myStrings` a property instead of a local variable (and learn about _scope_).

Comment: You'll also want to call `readFile()` at some point. Perhaps in `viewDidLoad`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable scope in Swift is limited to the brackets of the function. So to make `myStrings` available outside of your `readFile()` function, you need to declare it as a property for the class:

```
@IBOutlet var difficultyLevel: UILabel? // BTW your IBOutlet should not be weak
var i: Int = 0
var myStrings: [String]?
```

Since you are going to use the random functionality over and over, we can abstract the function like this

```
func randomString() -> String? {
     if let strings = myStrings {
         let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(myStrings.count)))
         return strings[randomIndex]
    }
    return nil
}
```

then your instantiation will be like this

```
if let content = data {
    myStrings = content.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.newlineCharacterSet())
    difficultyLevel.text = randomString()
}
```

Then, your `difficultybutton` function will be (with an abstracted random string function)

```
// Changed the name for better readibility
@IBAction func difficultyButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
     difficultyLevel.text = randomString()
}
```

Finally, there isn't any code that calls the `readFile` function, so you should add it to probably the `viewDidLoad` function as @CharlesCaldwell points out

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     readFile()
}
```